# Why does the Xbee retrieve different data?

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino, xbee

I had to take data from a temperature DS18B20 sensor and a HIH4000 humidity sensor, feed it into one Arduino board, which sends it through an XBee to another Xbee which is connected to another Arduino board, to which are also connected two sensors identical to the aforementioned ones. The 2nd Arduino is supposed to send data from 4 sensors to a database in the end.
My problem is that even though the Arduino boards receive good data from the sensors, when I send the data from the transmitter, the coordinator gives some weird output instead of the normal sensor values. I can see some repetition of the values but not in a specific order. It seems to be random. This are my programs:

```
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);
int DS18S20_Pin2 = 2;
OneWire dk(DS18S20_Pin2);
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(void) {
  float temperature1 = 1.0463*getTemp1()- 1.3705;
  int humidity1 = 0.1488*analogRead(A1)-22.587;
  Serial.println("SENSOR 2");
  Serial.println(temperature1); 
  Serial.println("SENSOR 4");
  Serial.println(humidity1);
  mySerial.println(temperature1);
  mySerial.println(humidity1);
  delay(1000);
}

float getTemp1(){
byte data1[12];
byte addr1[8];
if ( !dk.search(addr1)) {
      //no more sensors on chain, reset search
      dk.reset_search();
      return -1000;
  }
  if ( OneWire::crc8( addr1, 7) != addr1[7]) {
      Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
      return -1000;
  }
    if ( addr1[0] != 0x10 && addr1[0] != 0x28) {
      Serial.print("Device is not recognized");
      return -1000;
  }
  dk.reset();
  dk.select(addr1);
  dk.write(0x44,1);
  byte present1 = dk.reset();
  dk.select(addr1);
  dk.write(0xBE);
  for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) { // we need 9 bytes
    data1[j] = dk.read();
  }
  dk.reset_search();
  byte MSB1 = data1[1];
  byte LSB1 = data1[0];
  float tempRead1 = ((MSB1 << 8) | LSB1); //using two's compliment
  float TemperatureSum1= tempRead1 / 16;
  return TemperatureSum1;
}
```

This was for the transmitter. This is for the coordinator:

```
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);
int DS18S20_Pin = 2;
OneWire ds(DS18S20_Pin);  // on digital pin 2
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
  float temperature = 1.041*getTemp()- 1.1574;
  int humidity = 0.1509*analogRead(A1)-42.484;

  Serial.println("SENSOR 1");
  Serial.println(temperature);
  Serial.println("SENSOR 3");
  Serial.println(humidity);
  if(mySerial.available()){
    Serial.println(mySerial.read());
    Serial.println(mySerial.read());
  }

  delay(1000);
}

float getTemp(){
  byte data[12];
  byte addr[8];
  if ( !ds.search(addr)) {
      //no more sensors on chain, reset search
      ds.reset_search();
      return -1000;
  }
  if ( OneWire::crc8( addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
      Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
      return -1000;
  }
  if ( addr[0] != 0x10 && addr[0] != 0x28) {
      Serial.print("Device is not recognized");
      return -1000;
  }
  ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);
  ds.write(0x44,1); // start conversion, with parasite power on at the end
  byte present = ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);    
  ds.write(0xBE); // Read Scratchpad
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // we need 9 bytes
    data[i] = ds.read();
  }
  ds.reset_search();
  byte MSB = data[1];
  byte LSB = data[0];
  float tempRead = ((MSB << 8) | LSB); 
  float TemperatureSum = tempRead / 16;
  return TemperatureSum;
}
```

Comment: Is the coordinator running AT (transparent serial) firmware or API firmware?  What does the output look like?  Is the coordinator module configured with the correct baud rate?  If you swap the coordinator and router modules, do you see the same output?  If you connect the coordinator to a PC with a terminal program, do you see the correct output?

Comment: Hi, both the coordinator and the router were running AT. The output is somewhat random but you can see some of the values repeat. There is no specific pattern though. The baud rate is 9600 for everything. I tried to make the xbees run on API but now I can't seem to be able to make them communicate at all. Not even when I put them back on AT. I will work on this tomorrow and I will come up with updates

Comment: UP: I fixed the communication between the xbees. The problem was the version of the firmware. So now I have another question. After I upload the API firmwares, how do I make them communicate in XCTU? When I want to put a frame to send a message from an xbee to another I see the section "AT commands" with a red color. So I suppose I have to change the frame type. Which type exactly should I pick?

Comment: UP: I solved the problem. It was because I used mySerial.println instead of mySerial.write. Thank you anyway

Comment: Maybe you could write up an answer to your own question, explaining why `mySerial.println()` caused problems, and what happened when you switched to `mySerial.write()`.  That would help people in the future who find your question in a search.

Comment: Well I am not very good at C since I am a second year student and the C lectures will start in the third year, but I believe it might have to do with the type of the variable(float,int,string...). However, when I tried to use mySerial.println() of a letter I got the ASCII code for that letter. And mySerial.write() seems to have trouble with doubles so I actually split the decimals from the integer and used mySerial.write(integerpart); mySerial.write(","); mySerial.write(decimals);. Again I am not 100% certain if what I wrote is correct, but that would be my guess. I hope it helps.